# Cannot find source of IndexSearcher.search(Query query, Filter filter, int n)

Tags: java, lucene

I want to modify this method (implement my own version of it) but I can't find the real source. So far I've only found out that it is inherited from Searcher, and Searcher, inside of this method, calls search(createWeight(query), filter, n). But what is the actual code?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [version](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/lucene/lucene-3.3.0/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.java.html) for Lucene 3.3

Comment: do you know why it is not in 3.4 source?